# Difference between Cross-Cap, Mobius Band, and Real Projective Plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, mobius-band

I understand how the mobius band and the real projective plane are different (the first is a manifold with boundary, for example, while the second is a compact, closed surface and a true manifold).

**1.** Is a cross-cap the name for spaces which are homeomorphic to the mobius band and which are sewn into holes cut from surfaces in order to increase their non-orientable genus? (The orientable counterpart being handle attachment -- the mobius band, in contrast, has a "twist".)

**2.** Or is the cross-cap what results from the connected sum of a disk and a mobius band, i.e. the real projective plane?

**Core Question:**

> I.e. (up to homeomorphism) is a cross-cap **1.** a mobius band or **2.** a real projective plane? Or something else entirely?

The terminology does not seem to be consistent between sources, for instance Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cap, or the various mentions of the term "cross-cap" in Gross, Tucker, *Topological Graph Theory*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can search on the web for images of the cross-cap; it  is a model in 3 dimenions,  with self intersections,  of the projective plane.

The projective plane can also be seen as a Mobius band with a disc glued onto the boundary; but this cannot be dome in 3 dimensions. A representation of this gluing and its relation to rotations in 3 dimensions is shown in  part of this presentation [Out of Line](http://groupoids.org.uk/outofline/motion.html#motion).

Comment: So when people refer to doing surgery with cross caps, do they mean removing a disk from them and then attaching the resulting mobius band?