# Why does the only non-orientable surface embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology

As far as my understanding goes, if one has a closed (compact) surface and "cuts out" a disk, then the resulting object has a non-empty/non-trivial boundary.

It can be shown that any non-orientable surface *without* boundary cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (e.g. [A non orientable closed surface cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585026/a-non-orientable-closed-surface-cannot-be-embedded-into-mathbbr3), https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18987/why-cant-the-klein-bottle-embed-in-mathbbr3).

However, if we allow surfaces ***with*** boundary, then we can find a non-orientable surface which *does* embed into $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Möbius strip. As I understand, it can be formed by cutting out a disk from the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$. (Which corresponds to the fact that the boundary of both the disk and of the Möbius strip is a circle.)

Thus, it seems like the pathology which prevents $\mathbb{RP}^2$ from being embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the disk we cut out to get the Möbius strip (I think this disk is sometimes called the cross-cap, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876529/difference-between-cross-cap-mobius-band-and-real-projective-plane)).

> Is there a way to make rigorous the notion that only "certain types of twisting" are the only things which prevent a surface from being embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$?
>
> An example of such a twist is the twist necessary to glue a disk onto the Möbius strip.
>
> In other words, why does introducing boundaries to non-orientable surfaces (by cutting out a disk) suddenly make them embeddable?

The concept that a manifold with boundary could be less pathological than similar manifolds (i.e. of the same dimension and orientability) that do not have boundary is counter-intuitive for me, and want to understand what I am failing to take into account.

The fact that the Möbius strip has boundary clearly gives it interesting topological properties which non-orientable surfaces without boundary do not have, see for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXHHvoaSctc) on YouTube, however I don't have the impression that the video demonstrates how the boundary of the Möbius strip makes it embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It's not that *introducing* boundaries makes things embeddable, it's that *removing* discs makes them easier to embed. For instance, think of the standard [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#/media/File:Surface_of_Klein_bottle_with_traced_line.svg) of the Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^3$. It only intersects itself in a small region; if we cut out a disc containing that region (on the "fat" part, not the "thin" part), we get a surface with boundary that embeds (via the restriction of the immersion) in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So depending on our choice of immersion, wherever self-intersections appear, we can just cut out that part and get an embeddable surface with boundary?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.